# Function A calls function B, while function B calls function A: ESLint gives error: 'functionB' was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Say I have the following scenario: a function A is defined first and calls function B inside; then function B is defined and calls function A. The code as follows:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [action, setAction] = useState("walk");

  const functionA = () => {
    if (action === "walk") {
      functionB();
    }
    setAction("run");
  };

  const functionB = () => {
    if (action === "run") {
      functionA();
    }
    setAction("walk");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={functionA}>button A {action}</button>
      <button onClick={functionB}>button B {action}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Click first then the second button to see its effect. Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-joliot-6y39e?file=/src/App.js:23-536).

The code runs fine since I used `setAction` to make sure no loop happens. However ESLint is giving me error:

```
'functionB' was used before it was defined.
```

Is there something wrong with my code? I know I can disable the ESLint rule but I'm concerned.

Comment: The `const` function expressions don't get hoisted the same way a regular function declaration does. So linter knows that

Comment: If so why does it still work? Do I have to change the arrow function to an ordinary function definition to avoid this?

Comment: It executes ok because they don't get called until after they are defined

Comment: Up to you how you want to fix it. Linter shouldn't complain if they were regular declarations instead as they would be hoisted. But then you would have to do some binding in order to use the component `this` in them

Comment: @charlietfl can you answer my question below the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Eslint will complain because of the hoisting issue, but the code still works and it does work because the call itself is invoked after it is being defined(after you click the button), but Eslint doesn't know this and the only way to solve this is by using a regular function with `function` keyword.

```
  function functionA (){
    if (action === "walk") {
      functionB();
    }
    setAction("run");
  };

  function functionB (){
    if (action === "run") {
      functionA();
    }
    setAction("walk");
  };
```

Comment: what if I have a useCallback function like this: `const functionA = useCallback(() => {blabla}, [])`, how can I change it to a regular function?

Comment: In this case, you are right but still, Eslint is still right in giving you this error because it is better to follow the rules even in this corner case you discovered.
This still my opinion which is maybe wrong.